# Select text from a line using Robot Framework and selenium2library

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm able to fetch the entire Line using the xpath

```
" xpath=.//*[@id='projectTable_info']"
```

But I could not fetch the selected Text. 
Can any one give you idea?

```
<div id="projectTable_info" class="dataTables_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries</div>
```

Wanted to Pick selected Text i.e. total numbers of entries. It can be 1 or 100.

"Showing to  1 to 100 entries". should pick 100 from this line.This count will be changing when row is added .

Comment: Which number do you want? The first, the second or the third?

Comment: What does "could not fetch" mean? Are you getting back an empty string? Are you getting an error? Are you getting back the wrong string?

Comment: No error, i dont have an idea of picking selected text .it shows the total count "Showing to 1 to 20 entries."I should pick only 20 from that line.

Comment: So, you're saying you _are_ able to get `"Showing to 1 to 20 entries"`, and you're asking how to get the `"20"` out of that string?

Comment: I am able to get 20 alone using fetch from left and fetch from right.